# What abilities exist in the Potterverse and how common are they?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there a definitive list of what abilities exist in the Potterverse that cannot be learned by any magician and how rare they are?

The ones I am able to remember:

- Parselmouth

  - very rare
- Metamorphmagus

  - rare(?!)
  - I know that wizards can do the same with a potion. But they are not able to learn the ability itself and will not be able to do this at will without the portion.
- Magical Resistance(?)

  - Found [here](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-magical-powers-ranked/):

    > Certain witches and wizards have the ability to resist magic used against them, sometimes through genetics and sometimes through innate talent.
  - Can everybody learn this or what is somebody born with this talent and can then learn it?

I know there are other abilities such as Animagus that can be acquired by every wizard/witch with some training or Lycanthropy by being bit. That is not what I am interested in.

What I am also not interested in are non-wizard-abilities. So, dragons being able to spit fire is also not what I am looking for.

Comment: I would add Seers. They're very rare and it's hinted that the power is inherited in some fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the three mentioned in the question (Parselmouth, Metamorphmagus, Magical Resistance) I can think of a few more.

#### Maledictus

Nagini being the most notable example, a Maledictus is a blood curse that will eventually turn the witch into a beast permanently. It is carried from birth and passed down from the mother to daughter.

> **Skender:** Next in our little show of freaks and oddities, I present to you—a Maledictus! Once trapped in the jungles of Indonesia, she is the carrier of a blood curse. Such Underbeings are destined, through the course of their lives, to turn permanently into beasts. But look at her. So beautiful, yes? So desirable... but soon she will be trapped forever in a very different body. Every night, when she sleeps... mesdames et messieurs... she is forced to become— Over time, she will not be able to transform back. She will be forever trapped in the body of a snake.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 43</sub>

#### Veela Magic

A notable example is Fleur Delacour and according to [The *Harry Potter* Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/creature/sentient/veela/):

> Veela are female humanoid magical beings that have the ability to drive men uncontrollably wild, especially when they ‘turn on’ their charm or perform the sensual dance for which they’re known.

Comment: A curse isn't an ability. They have no kind of control over it, nor is it really an advantage.

Comment: @Jenayah It's a magical ability that comes about because of a curse. Also don't they have control over it until it completely changes them?

Comment: Making prophecies is another one.

Comment: @JenayahI never said it has to be an advantage. Just that that other wizards / witches must not be able to learn it.

Comment: If we count maledictus, we should also count obscurus, the ability to turn to black smoke when stressed.

Comment: @Shade ah, okay. The way I hear "ability", it implies an advantage, fair enough. TLC - I don't remember. It's not implied by the circus guy, although he might've phrased it this way for "show" reasons

Comment: @Jenayah Fair enough. Ability is IMHO simply something you can do. If it's useful or not then depends in which circumstances you are. Something very useful might be very disadventegous in another situation.

Comment: The OP may or may not be interested in giant-ish resistance to magic. Giants aren't wizards themselves (I'm not sure if it's impossible or not), but their offspring can be, such as Hagrid.